# media query in mass mailing odoo v12

Tags: css, sass, odoo, media-queries, odoo-12

i am trying to add a media query to my custom snippet template, but it does not seem to work, do you have any idea how to make news letter in mass mailing responsive?

thank you in advance.

- snippets_themes.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="s_mail_block_test" name="Test">
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div class="flex-item-left">1</div>
                    <div class="flex-item-right">2</div>
                    <div class="flex-item-left">3</div>
                </div>
        </template>

        <template id="email_designer_snippets_test" inherit_id="mass_mailing.email_designer_snippets">
            <xpath expr="//div[@id='email_designer_default_body']/div[hasclass('o_panel_body')]" position="inside">
                <t t-snippet="mass_mailing_snippet_test.s_mail_block_test" t-thumbnail="/mass_mailing_snippet_test/static/src/img/blocks/block_text_image.png"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

- custom.css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;

  width:270px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a one column-layout instead of a two-column layout */
@media (max-width: 375px) {
  .flex-item-right, .flex-item-left {
    flex: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: is your xml file actually using the css file?

Comment: @underflow my xml file uses both css and scss